# Problem with insert data in SQLite Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-sqlite

Another problem with my application in Android Studio. I try to add data in "SQLite", the code seems correct from my pov, considering that I'm at the beginning with programming java. It seems that something is wrong, does not show me the message "Added successfuly" and 'setText=" "' doesn't work.

Main java file - "MainFragment"

```
package com.example.licenta23;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AppComponentFactory;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

EditText actv1, edtModel, actv2, actv3, actv4, edtFabricatie, edtPret;
Button btnChoose, btnAdd, btnList;
ImageView imageView3;

final int REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY = 999;

public static SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;

private List<MarcaItem> marcaList;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    init(view);
    fillMarcaList();


    AutoCompleteTextView editText = view.findViewById(R.id.actv1);
    AutoCompleteMarcaAdapter adapter = new AutoCompleteMarcaAdapter(getActivity(), marcaList);
    editText.setAdapter(adapter);

    AutoCompleteTextView editText2 = view.findViewById(R.id.actv2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CAROSERIE);
    editText2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    AutoCompleteTextView editText3 = view.findViewById(R.id.actv3);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, COMBUSTIBIL);
    editText3.setAdapter(adapter3);

    AutoCompleteTextView editText4 = view.findViewById(R.id.actv4);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CULOARE);
    editText4.setAdapter(adapter4);




    return view;
}

private void fillMarcaList() {

    ...


    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(getActivity(), "CarDB.sqlite", null, 1);

    sqLiteHelper.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CAR (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, alegemarca VARCHAR, model VARCHAR, caroserie VARCHAR, combustibil VARCHAR, culoare VARCHAR, fabricatie VARCHAR, pret VARCHAR, image BLOG)");

    btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String[] permissions =  new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                return;

            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(permissions, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY); // triggers onRequestPermissionsResult() each time a permission is granted in 'permissions'
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission Already Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try{
                sqLiteHelper.insertData(
                        actv1.getText().toString().trim(),
                        edtModel.getText().toString().trim(),
                        actv2.getText().toString().trim(),
                        actv3.getText().toString().trim(),
                        actv4.getText().toString().trim(),
                        edtFabricatie.getText().toString().trim(),
                        edtPret.getText().toString().trim(),
                        imageViewToByte(imageView3)
                );
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Added successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                actv1.setText("");
                edtModel.setText("");
                actv2.setText("");
                actv3.setText("");
                actv4.setText("");
                edtFabricatie.setText("");
                edtPret.setText("");
                imageView3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY) {
        if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You don't have permission to acces file location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return;

    }

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {


    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            imageView3.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void init(View view){
    actv1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.actv1);
    edtModel = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtModel);
    actv2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.actv2);
    actv3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.actv3);
    actv4 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.actv4);
    edtFabricatie = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtFabricatie);
    edtPret = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtPret);
    btnChoose = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnChoose);
    btnAdd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnList = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnList);
    imageView3 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
}

public static byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView image) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}

}
```

SQLiteHelper :

```
package com.example.licenta23;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public SQLiteHelper(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

public void queryData(String sql){
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    database.execSQL(sql);
}

public void insertData(String alegemarca, String model, String caroserie, String combustibil, String culoare, String fabricatie, String pret, byte[] image) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO CAR VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
    statement.clearBindings();

    statement.bindString(1, alegemarca);
    statement.bindString(2, model);
    statement.bindString(3, caroserie);
    statement.bindString(4, combustibil);
    statement.bindString(5, culoare);
    statement.bindString(6, fabricatie);
    statement.bindString(7, pret);
    statement.bindBlob(8, image);

    statement.executeInsert();
}

public Cursor getData(String sql){
    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
    return database.rawQuery(sql, null);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look in your logcat for a stack trace that might be coming from that `catch` you have in  your add `onClick()`. I would point out that the you're trying to bind several more arguments than you have placeholder `?`s in your `INSERT` statement, so that's an issue, but we'll need that stack trace to be able to determine if it's the current one.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it you should use `database.prepareStatement` `statement.bindString` just like in this [tutorial](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/insert/)

```java
SQLiteStatement statement = database.prepareStatement(sql);
    statement.clearBindings();

    statement.setString(1, alegemarca);
    statement.setString(2, model);
    statement.setString(3, caroserie);
    statement.setString(4, combustibil);
    statement.setString(5, culoare);
    statement.setString(6, fabricatie);
    statement.setString(7, pret);
    statement.setBytes(8, readFile(image));

    statement.executeInsert();
```

PS: Note that I've changed your `bindBlob` to `setBytes` as it is said [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/jdbc-read-write-blob/)

Answer (score -2):

Try this one.this is my code.you replace according to your requirements

```
package com.softarena.alarmapplication.Database;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.softarena.alarmapplication.Models.AlarmModel;
import com.softarena.alarmapplication.Models.DaysModel;
import com.softarena.alarmapplication.Models.Fvt_dest_model;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "alarmapp.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
    public static final String TABLE_ALARM = "Alarm";
    public static final String TABLE_DAYS = "weekDays";
    public static final String TABLE_FVT_DEST = "fvt_destination";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_ALARM_TIME = "alarmtime";
    public static final String COLUMN_ALARM_NAME = "alarmname";
    public static final String COLUMN_ALARM_TUNE = "alarmtune";
    public static final String COLUMN_START_LOC = "startloc";
    public static final String COLUMN_START_LOC_LatLong = "startlatlong";
    public static final String COLUMN_END_LOC = "endloc";
    public static final String COLUMN_END_LOC_LatLong = "endlatlong";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIME_TO_REACH = "timetoreach";
    public static final String COLUMN_START_COUNTRY = "startcountry";
    public static final String COLUMN_END_COUNTRY = "endcountry";
    public static final String COLUMN_RADIUS = "radius";
    public static final String COLUMN_SNOOZE_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String COLUMN_LAST_RING_DATE = "ringdate";
    public static final String COLUMN_TRANSPORT_TYPE = "travel_by";

  public static final String CREATE_TABLE_ALARM =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ALARM + "("
                    + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                    + COLUMN_ALARM_TIME + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_ALARM_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_ALARM_TUNE + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_START_LOC + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_START_LOC_LatLong + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_END_LOC + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_END_LOC_LatLong + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_TIME_TO_REACH + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_START_COUNTRY + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_END_COUNTRY + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_RADIUS + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_SNOOZE_STATUS + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_LAST_RING_DATE + " TEXT, "
                    + COLUMN_TRANSPORT_TYPE + " TEXT "
                    + ")";


    public MainDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ALARM);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ALARM);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

 public boolean adddatainalarm(String alarmTime, String alarmName, String alarmtune, String startLoc, String startlatlong, String endLoc, String endlatlong, String timetoReach, String startCountry, String endCountry, String Radius, String Status, String date,String travelby) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        boolean add = false;

        contentValues.put(COLUMN_ALARM_TIME, alarmTime);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_ALARM_NAME, alarmName);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_ALARM_TUNE, alarmtune);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_START_LOC, startLoc);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_START_LOC_LatLong, startlatlong);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_END_LOC, endLoc);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_END_LOC_LatLong, endlatlong);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TIME_TO_REACH, timetoReach);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_START_COUNTRY, startCountry);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_END_COUNTRY, endCountry);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_RADIUS, Radius);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_SNOOZE_STATUS, Status);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LAST_RING_DATE, date);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TRANSPORT_TYPE, travelby);

        try {
            Long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_ALARM, null, contentValues);

            if (result == -1) {
                add = false;

            } else {
                add = true;
                Log.d("Database : ", "Data add successfully");
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Database error : ", "" + e);
        }
        return add;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is clearly not recommended to have such concataining parameters in command. You should look at tutorial and do the way of the OP and use a question mark (?) for each parameter.